# Generic type and performance

Tags: java, performance, generics

I'm wondering if using generic types through out the program will have any (significant)degrading performance effect on the application. I use a lot of collection objects(lists, sets, maps) and to give better flexibility to the application(this application has to be integrated into other application) I used only generic types instead of parameterizing them. Is this a common practice or does anyone have a suggestion/advice? Will there be any significant performance degrade?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "generic types instead of parameterizing them"? I think you meant you're using raw types (i.e. you don't specify the generic type information).

Comment: I suggest you use specific/parameterised types where you can, and where ever it improves clarity.

Comment: Even if the performance would be different, what would the cost be in terms of development time and bugs if you went the old-fasioned, non-generic way with casts and the like? That's significant too, and with language features like generics, more significant than actual performance considerations. If performance was a consideration, it'd be plastered all over all descriptions and tutorials on generics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There will be **no performance degradation at all**, because generics are effectively a "compile-time trick".

The compiler uses this information to reject certain type-unsafe practices that would otherwise appear at runtime, if not using generics.  During runtime only the raw classes (i.e. the upper bound of the generic parameters) are used, so the performance will be identical to *not* using generics, and just casting the classes yourself.

Comment: It might compile a bit slower though ;)

Answer (score 4):

As explained by other contributors, in most cases, using generics will not have any impact on performances. The only performance issue is when you have to replace a primitive type by its object type (for example, if you need to pass `int` as a generic parameter.

However, unless if you make an intensive usage of your object, the performance penalty is not visible. Consequently, you should start with generic and, if a performance issue due to this particular case occur, you can still replace your generic object by a class that use the primitive type. Early optimisation is evil.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for the phrase, "Early optimization is evil". I think I'm hung up on this and need to get out of it. After writing a method, I immediately start worrying about its performance and try to induce some "optimizations" wherever possible

Comment: It can be diagnose as "early optimization". Refactor, make it clearer, run it. If it seems to slow, think about it at an algorithmic level. If it can't be better, use tricks to optimise marginal issues as "primitive type as generics".

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. If you have to use an object under generics, then you had to also use an object in the same place before generics. e.g. if you use an `ArrayList<Integer>` now, then before there was generics, you would still have to put an `Integer` object into an `ArrayList`. Using an `int` would require a separate class, both with and without generics.

Comment: Yes. And? That's why early optimization is evil, because you need a separate class. However, the opint is: Using genrics in that case is a little slower due to boxing/unboxing.

Comment: But I'm saying that this has nothing to do with generics. You would need boxing/unboxing even without generics, if you likewise store it in an Object.

Comment: May be I see things differently because I'm used to Scala, which offers a nice way to avoid boxing/unboxing issues (see explanation here for example: http://blog.m1key.me/2010/03/programming-scala-28-showcase-type.html)

Answer (score 2):

Generic types are prividing *type safety* (any type casting issues will appear during compile-time not runtime) and are basically instructions to the compiler that are further 'erased' (*erasure*) and don't appear in that form (they are replaced by explicit casts) during runtime. Therefore, there is no performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

Using generics has no significant impact on performance or memory consumption.

The easiest proof for this is that generic type information is not generally available at runtime. That means that the JVM works exactly the same when there is generic type information as if there is none.

Using only raw types "to give flexibility" is a recipe for disaster, because you don't have type information on your collections and therefore can pass any kind of object around, even if your code is not prepared to handle it (i.e. if your code expects a collection of `String` objects, but it gets passed a collection with an `Integer` in it, it will throw a `ClassCastException`. With (correctly implemented) generics it would be a compile-time error).

Answer (score 0):

All your definitions of generics are design time only. Once you compile your program the JVM replaces all your definitions by casts. This is a small degrade in performance compared to coding your class to contain the correct type you need from the start and thus avoiding the cast.

But the degrade in performance is small and I strongly advice you to use generics when appropriate to increase readability and reusability of your code. You may of course consider this if you have a class with EXTREME heavy use of methods that will do these implicit casts and you are experiencing performance problems. Though not before than ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, no, it's all compile time magic. In some cases hidden runtime cost may exist.

```
   class A<T>
1     void f(T arg)

   class B extends A<String>
2     void f(String arg)

   A<String> a = new B();
3  a.f("blah");
```

Line 3 will have method 2 invoked. However, it first invokes method 1, but method 2 is not a traditional "overriding" method of 1, the signatures are different. Javac must bridge the two, and at runtime there is a cost from method 1 to method 2.

The cost could be optimized to nothing by JVM method inlining.